# How to do an jQuery ajax call from a numberfield using Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, textfield

I am doing a `fixeddeposit` project, in which I am having three models:

1)`fixeddeposit`
2)`interestrate`
3)`interestsetup`

When I open a `fixeddeposit`, I have to type the number of days(365/730/1095/1460 & 1825) from `number_field`. Then in another text box I want to update the `rate_of_interest` based upon the number(365/730/1095/1460 & 1825) I typed.

Rate_of_interest should be taken from rate which is in the interestrates table field. Kindly see the screenshot of my interestrates table below.

**Interestrates table**

[image][image]

Example:

If i type number 365 in fixeddeposit form(which is number_field). It automatically select rate 9.5% from interestrates table using AJAX function.

And, if a customer age is above 58, and i type number 365 in fixeddeposit form. It automatically select (rate 9.5% + senior increment 0.5% ) = 10.0% from interestrates table using AJAX function.

**Screenshot of FD**
[image]

I googled it for a solution but, results showing with collection_select alone. I want to do the same in number_field. Though, i am new to Ruby on Rails and AJAX i am struggling with it.

Comment: why not just add your ajax function on periods field change and send its value and dob value to your controller method, there depending on your logic manipulate your rate field

Comment: @Mandeep: I am very new to AJAX, so i don't know how to do it. Please help me. I am still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets go through the steps of ajax in rails

a. Create a route for your custom action, since we want to send data so it'll be post request

```
post "/rate" => "your_controller#calculate_rate" , as: "calculate_rate"
```

b. Write a javascript code that will listen to your periods input field.

```
$(document).on("change","#id_of_periods_input",function(){
  var periods = $(this).val();
  var age = $("#id_of_age_input").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/rate",
    data: { periods: periods, age: age } //this will enable you to use params[:periods] and params[:age] in your controller
  });
});
```

This will work but *i think it'll be better if you have some sort of button and when user clicks on it then calculate your rate of interest* because if you'll use *on change event then then lets say your **periods value is 365 so your ajax call will fire 3 times( first time when you enter 3 then for 6 and then for 5)***

If you want to use button then also you have to use same logic only this line will change

```
$(document).on("click","#id_of_btn",function(){
  // same logic
});
```

c. Getting your data in controller and performing your logic

```
def calculate_rate
  @periods = params[:periods]
  @age = params[:age]
  // perform your logic here and store rates value in lets say @rate
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js{}  #this will make rails look for a file named calculate_rate.js.erb in your views
  end
end
```

d. Filling rates input field by writing js in **calculate_rate.js.erb**

```
$("#id_of_rate_field").val(@rate);
```

Comment: Boss, I have calculate age using before_save function in fixeddeposit model. Then, how this is possible                     (var age = $("#fixeddeposit_age").val();) ?                         Can you please clear my doubt?

Comment: @Yogesh i thought you had age field in your form anyways instead of sending age you'll have to send date of birth fields( month, year and date) values and then inside your controller you'll have to calculate age

Comment: Hmm. I will try it and inform u.

Comment: Mandeep: I have tried this code in my controller but it doesn't work                                                       def calculate_rate
    periods = params[:periods]
    dateofbirth = params[:dateofbirth]
    age = (DateTime.now - params[:dateofbirth]/365)
    rateofinterest = Rateofinterest.select('interestrates.id, interestrates.rate, interestrates.seniorincrement, interestrates.superseniorincrement')
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html    
      format.js{}
      format.json{}
    end
  end

Comment: @Yogesh what do you mean by doesn't work? Can you elaborate on what is not working? You are not getting input field values in controller or what?

Comment: age = (DateTime.now - params[:dateofbirth]/365) I have used to save the customer age like this in my fixeddeposit controller. But, it is not saving.

Comment: what error are you getting? and params[:dateofbirth] might be a string value so change it into integer. Also it's difficult to debug here without much information so ask a new question with all the relevant code :)

Answer (score 1):

I see that the rate is dependent on `Time Period` and `Date of Birth`. So, one way to do it is to attach an event listener to the two input fields. So let's say, dob input field has `id = dob`, you can write simple jQuery to attach a listener like [$("#dob").change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)....

Now, inside the listener function, you update the value of Rate of Interest based on the values of Time Period and DOB. For this, you could write the ROI logic in the code or send an ajax request to Rails app and get Interest Rate from there.

Comment: There is another field called age which is used to calculate age. before_save :calculate_age
  def calculate_age
    self.age = ((DateTime.now - self.dateofbirth)/365)
  end

Comment: Periods is the field to determine the deposit period i.e., 365 days/730 days/1095 days/1460 days & 1825 days.

Comment: You can easily calculate age from dob in the event listener javascript code or ask the user to input age.. I don't understand where the problem is!

Comment: When opening fixed deposit user input the dob and i calculate the age in fixeddeposit model using the above code i commented.