# jQuery ajax call from a numberfield using Rails is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

For my application, I have fixeddeposits where we can create new fixeddeposits. Now, i want to update the rateofinterest field based upon the number(365/730/1095/1460 & 1825) I typed in the deposit period(number_field) and i have to check the customer age.

I have calculated customer age in fixeddeposits_controller. I don't know where i am wrong that too is not working.

```
Example 1:

1.1: If a customer age >58 && age<75,  i want to open the fixed deposit for 365days means i have  to sum the two fields rate(9.5%) + seniorincrement(0.5%) and then pass the value(10.0%) to rateofinterest field.

1.2: If a customer age >75,  i want to open the fixed deposit for 365days means i have  to sum the two fields rate(9.5%) + superseniorincrement(1.0%) and then pass the value(10.5%) to rateofinterest field.

1.3: If a customer age <58,  i want to open the fixed deposit for 365days means i have to pass the rate(9.5%) field value alone to rateofinterest field.
```

Where as(rate, seniorincrement, superseniorincrement)fields are from interestrates table.

For this i am using AJAX/JQUERY which was suggest by Mandeep in my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752435/how-to-do-an-jquery-ajax-call-from-a-numberfield-using-rails).

I have implemented, but its not working. I have attached the code i tried. Kindly check it and please give me some ideas.

**_form.html.erb**

```
   <%= form_for @fixeddeposit do |f| %>  

   <% if @fixeddeposit.errors.any? %>
   <h4>Couldn't open FD Account</h4>
   <ul>
   <% @fixeddeposit.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
   <li><%= error %></li>
   <% end %>
   </ul>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :customer_name, class:'required' %>
  <%= f.text_field :customername, :placeholder =>'Name' %>

  <%= f.label :date_of_birth, class:'required' %>
  <%= f.date_select :dateofbirth, { :include_blank => true, :start_year => 1900, :end_year => 2014 }, :id => "dateofbirth" %>


  <%= f.label :Periods, class:'required' %>
  <%= f.number_field :periods, :id => "fixeddeposit_periods", :placeholder => "Days", :class => "input-mini" %>

  <%= f.label :Rate_Of_Interest %>
  <%= f.text_field :rateofinterest, :id => "fixeddeposit_rateofinterest", :value => "", :disabled => true, :class => "input-medium" %>
  <span class="help-block">auto-generated</span>

  <div>      
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Open FD", class: "btn btn-primary" %>     
  <% end %>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).on("change","#fixeddeposit_periods",function(){
var periods = $(this).val();
var dateofbirth = $("#dateofbirth").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/rateofinterest",
data: { periods: periods, dateofbirth: dateofbirth }
});
});
```

**fixeddeposits_controller**

```
  def calculate_age(dateofbirth)
    @age = DateTime.now - dateofbirth/ 365
  end

  def calculate_rateofinterest
    @periods = params[:periods]
    @dateofbirth = params[:dateofbirth]
    calculate_age(@dateofbirth)
    if @age >= 58 && @age < 75
      @rateofinterest = Rateofinterest.select('interestrates.id, interestrates.seniorincrement')
    elsif @age >= 75
      @rateofinterest = Rateofinterest.select('interestrates.id, interestrates.superseniorincrement') 
    else
      @rateofinterest = Rateofinterest.select('interestrates.id, interestrates.rate')
    end
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html{ redirect_to fixeddeposits_path }    
   format.js{}
   format.json{}
   end
  end
```

**calculate_rateofinterest.js.erb**

```
$("#fixeddeposit_rateofinterest").val(@rate);
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :fixeddeposits do
resources :interestrates
end

post "/rateofinterest" => "fixeddeposits#calculate_rateofinterest" , as: "calculate_rateofinterest"
```

I don't know why it is not working. Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your js code replace

```
var dateofbirth = $("#fixeddeposit_dateofbirth").val();
```

with

```
// you have mentioned your dob field's id as 'dateofbirth'    
var dateofbirth = $("#dateofbirth").val();
```

---

In your controller, you need to call `calculate_age` method to have `@age` variable. Replace

```
@dateofbirth = params[:dateofbirth]
```

with

```
@dateofbirth = params[:dateofbirth]
calculate_age(@dateofbirth)
```

---

I'm not sure, why you have written `@age.save` in your `calculate_age` method definition. You may remove it.

---

Now in your `calculate_rateofinterest.js.erb` file replace

```
$("#interestrates_rate").val(@rate);
```

with

```
$("#fixeddeposit_rateofinterest").val(@rate);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have edited the code you suggested but this too is not working. . . :(

Comment: I am very new to RUBY ON RAILS and AJAX so i don't know how to see AJAX error.

Comment: You may check your rails server console or if it's on client side, you can check it in firebug (firefox) or just open your site in chrome and press F12, in console tab, you can see error by regenerating issue by following same steps

Comment: These two errors i'm getting (Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined application.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/defaults.js)

Comment: You need to check your rails server console to know the reason of 404 and for $, you need to include jquery file in your application.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57679/discussion-between-raj-and-yogesh).